# If $\phi(a_1v_1+a_2v_2)$ is polynomial function, then $\phi(a_1v_1+\cdots +a_mv_m)$ is as so?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

Sorry for my bad English.

Let $k$ be a filed,  $V$ be vector filed over $k$,  $\phi: V\to k$ be (set-theoric) map,and $n\ge 1$ be an integer .

We assume that  any $v_1, v_2\in V$, there is $n$-degree polynomial $f(X_1,X_2)\in k[X_1,X_2]$,
$\phi(a_1v_1+a_2v_2)=f(a_1,a_2)$ for all $a_1,a_2\in k$.

Then can we say it is true for all $m\ge 1$ as above?;

Any $v_1,\dots, v_m\in V$, is there  $n$-degree polynomial $f(X_1,\dots, X_m)\in k[X_1,\dots ,X_m]$,
$\phi(a_1v_1+\cdots+a_mv_m)=f(a_1,\dots, a_m)$ for all $a_1,\dots, a_m\in k$?

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Hello, you don't have to apologize for your English, but please add some of your own thoughts in the question. It would also be helpful if you tell us where this question comes from.

Comment: Does your polynomial depends on $v_1$ and $v_2$?

Comment: @ WhatsUp I think it’s true because I feel this hypothesis(i.e. it's true for $m＝2$) is very strong, but I can’t make polynomial for $m $. So I want to know the way of making the polynomial. Now I can’t understand even if field $k$ is real number field and $m＝3$ whose condition is very easy to imagine.

Comment: @ Diego Santos yes.